# SharePoint 2013 and Requirejs conflict

Tags: sharepoint, requirejs, sharepoint-2013, amd

A simple javascript application I wrote that uses Requriejs in SharePoint 2010 broke after porting over to Office 365.  After a quick glance at global variables I noticed that a naming conflict exists between the global variable 'define' in requirejs and SharePoint's init.js

Answer (score 4):

I have come across the exact same problem. But only since a few days! A week ago the exact same app worked perfect.

Maybe Microsoft changed something in the last update.

Kurt's fix didn't worked out for me. So i also had to override the other requirejs variables:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    define = undefined;
    requirejs = undefined;
    require = undefined;
</script>
```

Now everything is working.

Answer (score 3):

Naturally, the fix is to override 'define' near the end of the body before referencing  require.js like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    define = undefined;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/require.js" data-main="../App/main" />
```

I have yet to come across any repercussions for doing this, yet.  I am concluding that it is a fix.
Has anyone else came across this? If so has anyone noticed any problems?